# Main Window is closed through Dispose method on opening a new window

Tags: c#, .net, forms, ubuntu, monodevelop

**Background**

I switched operating systems and my C# forms application, that was working fine, is not running properly. I was using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows and am now using the latest release of MonoDevelop on Ubuntu.

**Issue**

I have a main form, a second form, and a third form that open in that order upon user request. The third window just displays a chart, no interactive buttons besides resize/close.

Upon running the third window, its `BeginInit()` method calls the main form `Dispose(bool)` method and subsequently closes the main window, then the second window, and the application hangs until I stop debugging from monodevelop GUI. I can't seem to find anything that points to why this is happening, though I am very new to MonoDevelop so perhaps I'm not looking in the right spots.

**Code**

Main Form:

```
// Open Second Window called "Diagnostics"
private void Plots_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Run(new Diagnostics(xmlDirectory));
}
```

Second "Diagnostics" Form:

```
// Set up stuff and run the Third window called "ChartDisplay"
private void GenerateChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // irrelevant code

    Application.Run(new ChartDisplay(datapoints, horizontalChoice, verticalChoice));

}
```

Third "ChartDisplay" form:

```
public ChartDisplay(List<object[]> data, string xAxisLabel, string yAxisLabel)
{
        InitializeComponent();

        // irrelevant code that doesn't get run
}
```

ChartDisplay.Designer:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend legend1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
    this.chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).BeginInit(); // last line to get called
    // ...
}
```

**Debugging**

Stepping into the `((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).BeginInit();` call in `Chart.Designer.cs` `InitializeComponent()` jumps straight to main form `Dispose(bool)` method as I mentioned before. Stepping into everything from there simply loops through the Dispose function until the main window is closed and then all other windows are closed, leaving the application hanging.

I put the callstack at `Dispose(bool)` the bottom of this post because it's lengthy.

**What I've tried**

The only help I've been able to find regarding similar issues suggests using `Application.Run(Form)`, instead of creating a new `Form` object and calling it's `Show()` method. As shown above I switched to this method and still no dice.

I tried adding a method to prevent the windows from being closed:

```
private void MainWindow_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

But this does nothing, doesn't even get called.

Stepping through everything does not really produce anything fruitful. It seems I can't actually step into the functions that are causing the issues such as `BeginIinit()`

**Call Stack at `Dispose(bool)`**

```
BitClean.MainWindow.Dispose(bool disposing) in /home/me/myapp/MainWindow.Designer.cs:15
System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose() in 
System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(System.Windows.Forms.Message m) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message m) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message m) in 
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc(System.IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Msg msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) in 
System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SendMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Windows.Forms.Msg message, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) in 
System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.SendMessage(System.IntPtr handle, System.Windows.Forms.Msg message, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Form.Close() in 
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit() in 
System.Windows.Forms.Application.OnThreadException(System.NotImplementedException t) in 
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.OnThreadException(System.NotImplementedException e) in 
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc(System.IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Msg msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) in 
System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Forms.MSG msg) in 
System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Forms.MSG msg) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunLoop(bool Modal, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(BitClean.Diagnostics mainForm) in 
BitClean.MainWindow.Plots_Click(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) in /home/me/myapp/MainWindow.cs:254
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.OnClick(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) in 
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) in 
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.HandleClick(int mouse_clicks, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) in 
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e, System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemEventType met) in 
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mea) in 
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mea) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmLButtonUp(System.Windows.Forms.Message m) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message m) in 
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message m) in 
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message m) in 
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message m) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message m) in 
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc(System.IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Msg msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) in 
System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Forms.MSG msg) in 
System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Forms.MSG msg) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunLoop(bool Modal, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) in 
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(BitClean.MainWindow mainForm) in 
BitClean.Program.Main() in /home/me/myapp/Program.cs:19
```

Comment: Ok this is interesting. So just to clarify, you originally tried form.Show() instead of Application.Run(), I assume in the Click event handlers in each of forms 1 and 2, you new'd a form and then called .show(). And that had the exact same issue? Call stack must have been different I assume.

Comment: your call stack has an unhandled exception being thrown which is causing your app to exit. Try putting a try..catch around the form show commands in the click event handlers, to trap that exception, then debug it from there to find out why it's happening.

Comment: @muszeo hey -- been a while since I worked on this, thanks for replying. I noticed the unhandled exception and from what I've read they're really hard to debug. Didn't think about using a try/catch so I will try that out next time. Thank you!